# What is the purpose of Docker.raw file on Mac OS Catalina?

Tags: macos, catalina, file, docker

I have Docker installed on my Mac OS Catalina and recently found very big file Docker.raw. It is 64 Gb.

I don’t understand why is it so big.

Is it really needed?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Docker for Mac stores Linux containers and images in a single, large file named Docker.raw. To reduce its size, after having pruned the unused docker objects (
https://docs.docker.com/config/pruning/ ), open the Docker Desktop preferences, and then under 'Resources' -> 'Advanced' -> 'Disk image size':

[image: Screenshot Resources -> Advanced -> Disk image size]

You can reduced file to less than 64GB. it's telling you how much is currently used by the current data. **Also Resizing to a smaller size will delete the disk image; all Docker images / containers will be lost.** Other settings will be preserved.

---

If you want to preserve the image,
you can use this script :
[clean-docker-for-mac.sh](https://gist.github.com/tyanyaw/6c1a83813965baab2c082e7076d4260c)

The script do this :

1. SAVE needed image to exclude
2. DELETE Docker.raw
3. LOAD chosen image back

Answer (score 13):

The answer to your question is in the [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/space/):

> **Disk utilization in Docker for Mac**
>
> Docker Desktop stores Linux containers and images in a single, large “disk image” file in the Mac filesystem. This is different from Docker on Linux, which usually stores containers and images in the /var/lib/docker directory.

The size of this file is big in your system because you have a lot of images and containers. You can reduce its site by [pruning unused objects](https://docs.docker.com/config/pruning/).

Comment: nope, the Docker.raw file has a fixed size on Mac OS, which is set in the preferences, and AFAIK the default size is 64GB on a 512G Macbook, and 32G on a 256G Macbook, which you can manually set it to a minimum of 8G I think, and it will take up that much disk space despite whether you have any images and containers or not.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way to reduce Docker.raw file size is by setting the preferences, as Docker official page states:

> Select the Docker icon and then select Preferences > Resources > Advanced.

[image: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/space/]

Source:https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/space/

Answer (score 1):

If you've tried pruning everything but still cannot get your disk usage back to normal, there is a utility in docker desktop in the `Troubleshoot` menu, which you can get to by clicking the little bug icon in the menu bar. Running the `Clean / Purge data` utility fixed this for me.

Comment: How does this answer the question? I don't really see the link...

Comment: Instruction that was selected as answer explains how to limit the size available for docker images, this shows a way how to clean docker data.

Answer (score 1):

It is very important to note that the "size of the file" and "how much space it occupies on your disk" are not the same thing, because [files may be "sparse"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file), and `Docker.raw` is indeed an example of a sparse file.

For example, on my disk it looks like I have a 60G `Docker.raw` file.  However, it only actually takes up 9.9G on disk:

```
% cd ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/data

% ls -lh Docker.raw 
-rw-r--r--@ 1 ken  staff    60G Jan 15 15:19 Docker.raw

% du -sh Docker.raw 
9.9G    Docker.raw
```

9.9G is still kinda big, but it makes sense given my usage.

So before tearing your hair out or taking drastic measures that might break something, make sure you actually have a problem worth solving.